# Migration to JAVA 11 - ECLIPSE && Tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, java-11

I am in the process of migrating from java 8 to java 11 for a spring project. I changed the JDK version to the eclipse IDE and even for the project plus the pom.xml file. When starting the project I got the following error, if anyone has an idea:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/context/request/async/CallableProcessingInterceptor
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)
at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:104)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:269)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:137)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:69)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:332)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:989)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5082)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
... 27 more
```

Answer (score 1):

For my case the solution was to look for the class (org/springframework/web/context/request/async/CallableProcessingInterceptor) in the jar of maven and also at the level of the war in the file system after I updated the project and it worked

Comment: In other words Eclipse forgot to deploy some of the dependencies? It happens in some specific circumstances. Removing and readding the application to the server usually works.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz Normally I did the cleaning and updating for maven and tomcat, for half a day, but finally when I check the war I found that the class exists after the project has started correctly